# Angular ng-include not working with laravel views : blade template

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am not much familiar with angularjs+blade template mixing. The blade template of laravel is not rendering ng-include (angularjs) html files. Or is it necessary to convert all included html to blade file as well? With core PHP it was not an issue. What could be the way to work in this situation?

```
  <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Nepstralia')}}</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-with-map.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>




<ng-include src="'nav.html'"> </ng-include>
<!-- <div id="toptarget"> &nbsp; </div><br> -->


<ng-include src="'carousel.html'"> </ng-include>
```

Non of the ng-included are loading in the blade template.  How to use angular ng-include with blade ?

Comment: try `<div ng-include src="'carousel.html'"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you must declare angular app by `ng-app` then try follwing:
index.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-with-map.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app>





<div ng-include="'nav.html'"> </div>
<!-- <div id="toptarget"> &nbsp; </div><br> -->


<div ng-include="'carousel.html'"> </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

carousel.html:

```
<h1>123</h1>
```

nav.html

```
<h2>145</h2>
```

if it isn't working may be your src is wrong .

Comment: used <body ng-app style='background: #e2e2e2;'> but hasn't been working

Comment: did you put ng-include in div tag ?

Comment: Yeah still not working :
 <div ng-include src="'nav.html'"> </ng-include>

May be I am missing something?

I have my design included using angularjs. I didn't like to use blade @include(). I thought it should be working because it is frontend.

Comment: i update my answer follow step by step and if it work check answer .thanks

Comment: I am marking this as answer because , there was an issue with permission/laravel. Thanks for answer @Aref Zamani